# Apt-get SSL client certificate not working on 16.04 (Error while reading file)

Tags: apt, ssl, https, tls

I ported the same working SSL client key/certificate and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01_https_client_cert` rule from an (working) 14.04 VM to a fresh 16.04 installation.

I am able to use the SSL client certificate to access the apt repo via `curl` but `apt-get update` complains with this error:

```
6% [Working]* Hostname example.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to example.com (11.22.33.44) port 443 (#29)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* error reading X.509 key or certificate file: Error while reading file.
* Closing connection 29
Ign:5 https://example.com/apt release/main all Packages
```

---

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01_ssl_client_auth` is the same on both systems:

```
Debug::Acquire::https "true";
Acquire::https::example.com::SslCert "/opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.crt";
Acquire::https::example.com::SslKey "/opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.key";
```

---

Permissions are the same on both machines:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ namei -mo /opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.crt
f: /opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.crt
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
 drwxr-sr-x ubuntu ubuntu opt
 drwxrwsr-x ubuntu ubuntu example
 drwxrws--- ubuntu ubuntu keyring
 -rw-rw---- ubuntu ubuntu ssl_client.crt
```

---

Trivia:

1. Removing the `01_ssl_client_auth` rule returns the expected `403` forbidden response (as repo requires client certificate)
2. `curl` works just fine like so:

   ```
   curl --cert /opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.crt --key /opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.key https://example.com/apt/

   Connected to example.com (11.22.33.44) port 443 (#0)
   found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
   found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
   ALPN, offering http/1.1
   SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        server certificate verification OK
        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
        common name: *.example.com (matched)
        server certificate expiration date OK
        server certificate activation date OK
        certificate public key: RSA
          (snip)
   ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
   GET /apt/ HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com
   User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
   Accept: */*

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
   Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 01:18:30 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Connection: keep-alive
   ```
3. And of course `apt-get` and `curl` both work on the original system with same `apt.conf.d` and cert...

---

Anything else I should look at? Was there some change from crt/key to pem in apt-get or something?

Comment: OK... So I have it working by setting `+rw` for the OTHER permission. But this is still different than behavior for `apt-get` in 14.04 so I am curious for explanation. Does `apt` run as separate user now than root? E.g. `chmod 666 /opt/example/keyring` and `chmod 666 /opt/example/keyring/ssl_client.*`. Thanks! (And yeah simply `+r` probably would suffice.)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able find more details from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Apt_1.2

Recommend settings is copy the cert and keys to a different directory and change the user permissions to

> _apt:nogroup

and configure

> apt_transport_https

setup to use the new path.

```
Acquire::https::cdn-mirror.insnw.net::CaInfo "/new/path/ca.crt";
Acquire::https::cdn-mirror.insnw.net::SslCert "/new/path.crt";
Acquire::https::cdn-mirror.insnw.net::SslKey  "/new/path.key"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Apt tries hard to drop permissions and run as the `_apt` user. I don't remember when that switch happened but it was fairly recent (i.e. likely to be after 14.04). So, having fixed my similar problem the same way you did (i.e. made sure that `a+rx` was available on all directories leading up to the cert I wanted `_apt` to use) I think it's safe to say you've identified the problem correctly.

Comment: For everyone looking here: **The recommended way is "chown _apt:root FILE && chmod 400 FILE" at the moment** See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1668944